# Self-assigned IP address

Tags: macos, macbook, dhcp

I sometimes have problems dropping IP addresses after changing networks and get stuck with a self-assigned IP that I cannot drop by hitting the renew "DHCP Lease" button on my Mac OS X.5 Leopard. The only work around is to manually give myself a "good" IP, shut down my computer, then boot up and switch back to regular DHCP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somtimes issues like these can arise from malformed network preferences. Try deleting (or just moving/renaming) these files:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some fairly unpleasant instructions from apple http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1920

Answer (score 0):

Connecting using the plain WEP password was allowing me to connect (to a link sys Wi-Fi) but DHCP didn’t work and I got the dreaded self-assigned address.

To fix it we logged in using the HEX version of the same key (which we found by looking on the router via a wired connection).

On network preferences, select Network Name `Join Other Network...` then type in the name of your own network, select WEP...HEX. and enter the HEX version of the WEP key.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the problem with your IP Address. `169.254.*.*` is an address reserved for local ip address. If your `DHCP server` uses that address then you could not connect to the internet.

Please check this [Internet connection does not work with an IP address space of 169.254.xxx.xxx from ISP, router, or manual configuration](http://support.apple.com/en-in/TS3798)